# Failed to encrypt sub-resource payload and the error is: Failed to encrypted linked service credentials on self-hosted IR

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I am developing an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) solution using .NET and Azure Data Factory to move data from an on-premises SQL Server to Azure. Self-hosted IR is set up correctly and is running on Azure Portal, but when I run the code I get this exception:

> Failed to encrypt sub-resource payload and error is: Failed to encrypted linked service credentials on self-hosted IR reason is: InternalServerError, error message is: Internal Server Error..

`ConnectionString` for the on-premises SQL Server server is in plain text and not encrypted.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself, and it works. I hope it helps someone who also encounters the same problem.

You need to set the value for `EncryptedCredential` and don't need to set the `Password` property.

[image]

And set `Connection String` like this:

[image]

Comment: I had the same error message using terraform resource `azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database` when the connection string was malformed (extra ;) or missing a required field, in case that helps anyone else landing here.